# Dynamically specify the Dockerfile base image based on the package.json defined node version

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am currently working in an environment where there are multiple node projects, some running on a 14.* node docker image, some on 16.*
The problem I faced was that I didn't realize the Dockerfile was obsolete and that the app would not run as it has been developed under 16.* while the Dockerfile specified a node environment in 14.*

I was wondering if there would be a way to reduce the possible amount of code that has to be modified if our structure decides to start implementing projects in other versions than the ones we currently use. After thinking about it, I ended up with two main axes of thoughts:

- The environment is set (Dockerfile), the app should be developed under the environment specifications
- The environment needs to be set according to the app

After some research I ran into this [article](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/use-arg-dockerfile-dynamic-image-specification) about dynamic image specification. Now this would make it pretty nice as we could dynamically somehow pass as an argument a version of the node image we would want to install for our environment.
This would require two things:

- As a dev, I must define the node version in my package.json
- A script must be able to read from that package.json and launch the `docker build` with the parameter it got and possibly catch the error if it is not defined.

Is this a recommended pattern to work? I believe it would reduce the amount of manual code changes in case of version updates but at the same time seeing the lack of documentation towards this use case I don't feel like this is a common thing.

Comment: To me it sounds like you develop and test in a non-Docker environment and only dockerize late in your process. You might think about developing and testing using Docker. That way you'd catch errors like that earlier. And your test environment and production environment would look more alike - which is always good, imo.

Comment: No we do develop and test in docker environments. The goal of that question is to find a way to reduce the locations of required modifications when upgrading the nodejs version on which the app is supposed to be developed/ran